# JQuery Datepicker Month and year data maintaing

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery Datepicker, I am selecting only month and year and I am getting the value and assigning the value to a text box. If I want to select another month or year the value in text box is resetting to the default dropdown value. I am unable to maintain the selected value in dropdown's.

Can any one suggest how to maintain it.

```js
 <script src="../SiteAssets/MedcomJs/Custom jq-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../SiteAssets/MedcomJs/jQueryv1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../SiteAssets/MedcomCss/Jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 $( "#SCAactionmonthss" ).next().bind("click",function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar,.ui-datepicker-next,.ui-datepicker-prev").css("display","none");
        var month=  $(".ui-datepicker-month").find('option:selected').text();
        var year=  $(".ui-datepicker-year").find('option:selected').text();
        $("#SCAactionmonthss").val(month+" "+year);
    });
    
    $(document).on("keyup keypress focus", $( "#SCAactionmonthss" ).next(), function(e) {
        if(e.which==9){
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar,.ui-datepicker-next,.ui-datepicker-prev").css("display","none");
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/_layouts/15/images/calendar_25.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            //buttonText: "Select Month",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'M yy',
            minDate: new Date(),
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(".date-picker").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", dateText);
            },
        }).focus(function() {
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar,.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next").remove();
            var month=  $(".ui-datepicker-month").find('option:selected').text();
            var year=  $(".ui-datepicker-year").find('option:selected').text();
            $("#SCAactionmonthss").val(month+" "+year);
        });
      
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="dpicker"> 
     <input name="startDate" id="SCAactionmonthss" class=" date-picker formdatepicker"  /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Check below answer how to maintain month year data

Answer (score 0):

On `focus` bind for event of `month` and `year` selection change.

On selection change `setDate` with selected value.

```
$(".date-picker").focus(function() {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    //add event to perform on done button click
    $(".ui-datepicker-month, .ui-datepicker-year").on('change', function() {
      var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      $(".date-picker").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      $(".date-picker").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    });
  });
```

```js
$("#SCAactionmonthss").next().bind("click", function() {
  $(".ui-datepicker-calendar,.ui-datepicker-next,.ui-datepicker-prev").css("display", "none");
  var month = $(".ui-datepicker-month").find('option:selected').text();
  var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year").find('option:selected').text();
  $("#SCAactionmonthss").val(month + " " + year);
});

$(document).on("keyup keypress focus", $("#SCAactionmonthss").next(), function(e) {
  if (e.which == 9) {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar,.ui-datepicker-next,.ui-datepicker-prev").css("display", "none");
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    //buttonText: "Select Month",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'M yy',
    minDate: new Date()
  });


  $(".date-picker").focus(function() {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    //add event to perform on done button click
    $(".ui-datepicker-month, .ui-datepicker-year").on('change', function() {
      var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      $(".date-picker").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      $(".date-picker").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div class="dpicker">
  <input name="startDate" id="SCAactionmonthss" class="date-picker formdatepicker" />
</div>
```